# Vue, using multiple components in one export call

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a single page that is built in vue where I have one export default block and then multiple components outside of it. The current problem is that I have an input inside of the 'Tabs' template on my page and when I call a function with it, it says it's not a function.

I think the issue is that it's not seeing it as a global function. Is there a way to cleanly take the two `Vue.component` blocks and put them all together into the main `export default` block?

```
<script>
import { Multipane, MultipaneResizer } from 'vue-multipane';

Vue.component('tabs', {
 template: `
    <div>
        <div class="tabs">
          <ul>
            <li v-for="tab in tabs" :class="{ 'is-active': tab.isActive }">
                <a :href="tab.href" @click="selectTab(tab)">{{ tab.name }}</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="tabs-details">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    </div>
  `,

data() {
return { 
  tabs: [],
  inputName: '',
 };
},

created() {

this.tabs = this.$children;

},
methods: {
setInputName(str) {
  this.inputName = str;
},
selectTab(selectedTab) {
  this.tabs.forEach(tab => {
    tab.isActive = tab.name == selectedTab.name;
  });
} } });

Vue.component('tab', {

template: `

    <div v-show="isActive"><slot></slot></div>

`,

props: {
name: { required: true },
selected: { default: false } },


data() {

return {
  isActive: false,
  inputName: '', 
};


},

computed: {

href() {
  return '#' + this.name.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-');
} },

methods: {
setInputName(str) {
  this.inputName = str;
}
}

mounted() {

this.isActive = this.selected;

} });


export default {
components: {
  Multipane,
  MultipaneResizer,
},
data () {
    return {
        events: [],
        inputName: '',
    }
},
created() {
  this.fetchTasks();
},
computed: {

},
methods: {
fetchTasks() {
axios.get('/ticket/dashboard')
  .then(response => {
    // // handle success
    // console.log('test')
    // console.log(response)

    this.events = response.data.map(({task_comment, ...item}) => ({
      ...item,
      title: task_comment
    }));

    console.log(this.events);

  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error)
  })
  .finally(function() {})
}
},
setInputName(str) {
  this.inputName = str;
}
};
</script>
```

Comment: I would add a parent component that imports the two components.

Comment: Would that work if, say, I had an element in the Tabs template html that called the function in the main export vue code?

Comment: Yup. I do something like that all the time. I would write an answer with some example code, but I don't code my components like you do (straight in the script-tags). I usually make a .vue-file and write it in there. So the notation is a bit difference. :-/

Comment: @zeth makes sense, thanks for the help!